# Why history command is default disabled for bash scripts

Tags: bash

I've made a little bash script which clean some files (*~, *#, etc.) and the terminal but I've seen that the history command is disabled by default in non-interactive shells by bash (I wanted to add "history -c").

I'm just curious of why ?

Comment: ... Because a history only makes sense for interactive shells?

Comment: I think OP wants to clear the shell history, not display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In General

- For an overwhelming majority of scripts, reading dotfiles for history would be pure startup-time overhead, with that content never used at runtime. This would make **all** shell scripts take longer to start up, with no compensating benefit.
- If noninteractive scripts **did** support history expansion, this would make their behavior dependent on prior interactive actions, thus harder to predict and different between invocations. This is, in particular, a compelling reason not to have `set -H` on by default in noninteractive script invocation.
- History is specified in the User Portability Utilities section of the POSIX sh standard, which is focused around support for interactive scripting. Quoting from the standard, with emphasis added:

  > **When the sh utility is being used interactively,** it shall maintain a list of commands previously entered from the terminal in the file named by the `HISTFILE` environment variable. The type, size, and internal format of this file are unspecified. Multiple `sh` processes can share access to the file for a user, if file access permissions allow this; see the description of the `HISTFILE` environment variable.

---

Finally, some context:

`history -c` is needed in an interactive script because that interactive shell will be writing a new copy of `HISTFILE` when it exits; if you didn't use a special command, it would potentially write back content that you instead want to clear. In a noninteractive shell, it won't be writing any history anyhow, so you might as well simply delete or truncate the history file.

Comment: So for example if I do something like `> $HISTFILE` it'll do the same has "history -c" ?

Comment: Pretty much. It won't do anything to prevent the shell that *started* your script from writing contents back to the history file when it exits, but there's not much you *can* do about that -- `history -c` in one shell doesn't have a mechanism to tell other shells how to behave either.