# History (or fc) commands don't work from within a script

Tags: shell, command-history

When using tools like `grep` or some `git` output (for `status`, for example), I often want to make something with the (last) file returned in the list, like copying it to the clipboard or viewing it.

I'd like to automate that with a script that would rerun the last command, and identify the last returned file name, with such as script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Retrieve the last command from the shell history.
last_command=$(history | tail -n 1)

# Check if the last command is empty.
if [ -z "$last_command" ]; then
    printf >&2 "No command found in the shell history.\n"
    exit 2
fi

# Run the last command and capture its output.
command_output=$($last_command)

# Extract the last line (assuming it's a list of files).
last_file=$(printf "%s" "$command_output" | tail -n 1)

# Debugging information.
printf "Last file: %s\n" "$last_file"
```

Though, for whatever reason which escapes me, `history` does return the last command when run interactively from the command line, but it does not when run from the script.  Hence `last_command` is always empty...

With `set -x`:

```
++ history
++ tail -n 1
+ last_command=
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ printf 'No command found in the shell history.\n'
No command found in the shell history.
+ exit 2
```

Any idea?

(PS- I've also tried many different alternatives, such as using `fc`, but with no more success.)

**EDIT --** Changing the first command to:

```
history_file="$HOME/.bash_history"
last_command=$(tail -n 1 "$history_file")
```

shows me another last command than the real last command outputted by `history`!??

Comment: You need to make sure that the shell that executes the script is the same ones you wrote those commands in the script for. That's what the first line is for: for example, `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: My shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, and I'm using the script from Bash also...

Comment: I will update the script above... but the problem remains...

Comment: When a script is executed, it runs in a subshell, and the history command is specific to each shell session. That's why you're not getting the desired result when trying to use history within a script

Comment: Dear Aikan, that seems to be the core explanation. But is there a way to circumvent than?  (Somhow, accessing to the parent's shell history, then.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why history command is default disabled for bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800345/why-history-command-is-default-disabled-for-bash-scripts)

Comment: Not enough...
I tried to change the first command to:
`history_file="$HOME/.bash_history"
last_command=$(tail -n 1 "$history_file" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]*[[:space:]]*//')`, but this shows me another last command than the real last command outputted by `history`... I don't understand...

Comment: I never tried it myself, but did you consider turning on history inside your script, i.e. `set -o history`?

Comment: that wasn't set, but (now that it is) the result is no different... ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the man page indicates, you have to `set -o history` to make history available to scripts; but even then, the feature is enabled independently from your current interactive history. Since this seems like it's intended entirely for interactive use, it's probably something you should make into a function in your `.bash_profile` or similar instead.

```
rerun () {
    local last_command=$(history 2 | sed -n 's/^ *[1-9][0-9]* *//p;q')

    # Check if the last command is empty.
    if [ -z "$last_command" ]; then
        echo "rerun: No command found in the shell history" >&2
        return 2
    fi

    $last_command | tail -n 1
}
```

This is still way too simplistic if the last command was a pipeline. You want to `eval` the last command to really repeat it.

(I find this too limited to be of actual use. Just press the up arrow and add `| tail -n1 | xargs cp -t dest` to copy the last file in particular someplace. More often, I want to copy or otherwise manipulate all the files or lines.)

Comment: So, the trick was to avoid making a scripting, but writing a function instead!  OK!!!

Comment: It does what I want, even with pipes... The last command would be, for example, `git modified-files | grep .js` and that whole line will be rerun... as desired...

Comment: Only improvement: need to add `HISTTIMEFORMAT=""`in front of `history 2` to be sure that we only get the number of the command, followed by the command itself.

Comment: Except without the `eval`, it will treat `|` and `grep` as arguments to `git`. (And by the way, maybe have someone look at your keyboard; the period key seems to jam randomly.)

Comment: That's right: I do have `eval` in my case, like in my original script.  Thanks for the explanation!